# Gradle and Android Studio build fails

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've always been able to use **Android Studio**. I upgraded to **Gradle** Version **2.9** and I keep getting errors while building.
I get the following error:

```
Gradle:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using 
BuildScopeServices.createScriptObjectConfigurerFactory().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I've tried running it with **--stacktrace** and **--info**but it doesn't seem to help much.
Should I post it here to get help?

EDIT(My **--debug** output):

```
19:39:58.668 [DEBUG]   
[org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices]
Unable to initialize native-platform. 
Failure net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Failed to load
native library 'libnative-platform.dylib' for Mac OS X x86_64.
caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/Users/Johnwon/.gradle/native/19/osx-amd64/libnative- platform.dylib.lock (Permission denied)
19:39:58.718 [DEBUG]  [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.FileSystemServices] Native-platform file system integration is not available. Continuing with fallback.
19:39:58.721 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.FileSystemServices] Using UnsupportedSymlink implementation.
19:39:58.723 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.FileSystemServices] Using JDK 7 file service org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.jdk7.PosixJdk7FilePermissionHandler
19:39:59.522 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.JavaSystemPropertiesProxySettings] Found java system property 'http.nonProxyHosts': local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16. Will ignore proxy settings for these hosts.
```

Answer (score 3):

**If nothing seems to work, then do this**

> Just delete your .gradle folder
>
> Located here C:\Users\username.gradle (**for Windows**)

Comment: I tried searching it on mac, couldn't figure it out where it is located...well when you find it , kindly comment as reply...a friend of mine has a similar issue on mac...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this was caused by a 32-bit JVM installed on a 64-bit machine (I was using (jdk-8u92-linux-**i586**.tar.gz).

Switching to a x64 JDK install (jdk-8u92-linux-**x64**.tar.gz) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was being caused by lack of permission in the file-system. 
I just change the directory owner and it starts to work:

```
sudo chown -fR $(whoami):staff /opt/gradle-4.6
```